# Input String was not in correct format in C#

Tags: c#

Not sure how to fix this. I am a noob to C#.
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBnU8.jpg)

Comment: Show us teh codez

Comment: Please don't post screenshots - not everyone can see them (firewall restrictions, mobile devices, etc).

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Don't post screenshots of text, include the code/text in the question itself.

Comment: What is the value of txtbox1.Text

Comment: More than likely your input is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextBox contains not a valid integer, try this code

```
public void txtbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(txtbox1.Text, out number))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Number is invalid");
    }

    if (number == 2112)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        return;
    }

    this.BackColor = Color.HotPink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wherever user input is concerned use **validation** (either in the code behind or on the textbox, ideally both).  Most likely your textbox does not contain an integer value. Try this:

```
int number;
if(Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out number))
{
    // Logic on validated input
} 
else  
{
    // Error message
}
```